# Direct link to groups listing in chatter

Tags: chatter

Im working on some custom pages for chatter and I realized the "groups", "topics" and "messages" pages all share a single url so as far as i can tell theres no way to link directly to these pages, any ideas on how i might get a simple link to the "Groups" listing for example?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the direct links for Groups, Messages and Topics.

**Groups** = https://[SALESFORCEINSTANCE]/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage?listViewType=groups

**Topics** = https://[SALESFORCEINSTANCE]/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage?listViewType=topics

**Messages** = https://[SALESFORCEINSTANCE]/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage?deepLinkType=directMessage

I believe this will only work on the Aloha (or classic) UI.